# Create online store with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, online-store

Does anyone know how to create an online store with wordpress? Is there something like a plugin for that purpose? Thank you very much!

Comment: Purchase or download an e-commerce wordpress theme and go through the documentation for that particular theme.

Comment: wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce is my weapon of choice: http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/
Very flexible theming and is well maintained with updates. It will help you set up a basic webshop. For advanced functionality you might need to purchase plugins.

Had less satisfying experience with http://getshopped.org/. But they seem to be updating it lately for the better.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of resources out there which will show you how to turn your WordPress into an online store. One the most popular plugins is WooCommerce.
Below I added 2 links which could help. The first talks about the features of WooCommerce and the second shows you how to install WooCommerce.

[Transform your WordPress website into an online store with WooCommerce](https://www.wpspartans.com/transform-your-wordpress-website-into-an-online-store-with-woocommerce/)

[Installing and Configuring WooCommerce In WordPress](https://www.wpspartans.com/installing-and-configuring-woocommerce-in-wordpress/)

The website powr.io also has a very nice plugin which could also be used to setup an online store with WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

There are many free plugins available to build online store in WordPress. They are full of inbuilt features and powerful enough to create a multi-million dollar e-commerce website. All depends on your imagination and strategy of working.
Some very powerful and free plugins are listed below.

1.WooCommerce (recommended)

2.WP eCommerce (second best in my opinion)

3.Easy Digital Downloads

4.Ecwid

5.Jigoshop

6.MarketPress

7.iThemes Exchange

They all are free with some limitations, But they also have pro, ultimate version to upgrade which will help you gain more control and easily manageable website.